# Composing functions in scala

Tags: scala

I learn scala in university and I cannot understand how to use map, flatmap and Option. Here's couple functions from my lab. I know how to implement first but I have no idea how to deal with second? So, the question: how to implement second function without changing it's signature (using map and flatmap)?

```
def testCompose[A, B, C, D](f: A => B)
                             (g: B => C)
                             (h: C => D): A => D = h compose g compose f


  def testMapFlatMap[A, B, C, D](f: A => Option[B])
                                (g: B => Option[C])
                                (h: C => D): Option[A] => Option[D] = // help
```

Comment: Подсказки: `_ flatMap f: Option[A] => Option[B]`, `_ map h: Option[C] => Option[D]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Результат функции `testMapFlatMap` - это функция `Option[A] => Option[D]`. Поэтому можно написать:

```scala
def testMapFlatMap[A, B, C, D](f: A => Option[B])
                              (g: B => Option[C])
                              (h: C => D): Option[A] => Option[D] = { a =>
  // остальной код
}
```

В этой функции входной параметр - `Option`. Для типа `Option` в стандартной библиотеке scala определены функции `flatMap` и `map`.

Сигнатура `flatMap` для `Option`:

```scala
def flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): Option[B]
```

Сигнатура `map` для `Option`:

```scala
def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B]
```

Используя всё вышесказанное, можно реализовать функцию `testMapFlatMap`:

```scala
def testMapFlatMap[A, B, C, D](f: A => Option[B])
                              (g: B => Option[C])
                              (h: C => D): Option[A] => Option[D] = { a =>
  a flatMap f flatMap g map h
}
```

Comment: здесь общаются на русском. переведите, пожалуйста, ваш ответ, нажав [edit]